# Determining size of a future file while data is still in memory

Tags: c#

This is C#/.NET 2.0.

So I have string that contains the future contents of an XML file. It contains metadata and binary data from image files. I would like to somehow determine how big the XML file will be once I write the data in the string to the file system.

I've tried the following and neither works:

```
Console.Out.WriteLine("Size: " + data.Length/1024 + "KB");
```

and

```
Console.Out.WriteLine("Size: " + (data.Length * sizeof(char))/1024 + "KB");
```

Neither works (the actual size of the resulting file deviates from what is returned from either of these methods). I'm obviously missing something here. Any help would be appreciated.

XML Serialization:

```
// doc is an XMLDocument that I've built previously
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
doc.Save(sw);
string XMLAsString = sw.ToString();
```

Writing to file system (XMLAsString passed to this function as variable named data):

```
Random rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);      
FileStream fs = File.Open(@"C:\testout" + rnd.Next(1000).ToString() +  ".txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
app.Diagnostics.Write("Size of XML: " + (data.Length * sizeof(char))/1024 + "KB");
sw.Write(data);
sw.Close();
fs.Close();
```

Thanks

Comment: How are you doing your xml-serialization?

Comment: The first thing I would do is divide by 1024 instead of 1000.  That should help with the kb size.

Comment: How are you writing data to the filesystem?

Comment: @JFV: That (above) looks like 1024 to me...

Comment: I changed it to 1024 shortly after posting the question. :) It's still off though.

Comment: I don't know C# very well, so I can't tell from looking at the code, but is it possible that some of the effects you're seeing are the result of line ending translations between \n in memory and \r\n on disk?

Comment: In addition to the other comments, how are you checking the size of the file in the file system?  Are you using explorer?  The actual amount of space taken up by the file on disk may be different because of the cluster size used on the hard disk.  This can vary from disk to disk.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're missing how the encoding process works.  Try this:

```
string data = "this is what I'm writing";
byte[] mybytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
```

The size of the array is exactly the number of bytes that it should take up on disk if it's being written in a somewhat "normal" way, as UTF8 is the default encoding for text output (I think).  There may be an extra EOF (End Of File) character written, or not, but you should be really close with that.

Edit: I think it's worth it for everybody to remember that characters in C#/.NET are NOT one byte long, but two, and are unicode characters, that are then *encoded* to whatever the output format needs.  That's why any approach with `data.Length*sizeof(char)` would not work.

Comment: Oh, and FYI, you are right in that this returns a value VERY slightly under what eventually ends up on the FS. =) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

In NTFS, if your file system is set to compress, the final file might be smaller than what your actual file might be. Is that your problem?

Comment: Interesting. Yes, the value returned from the methods are always greater than the actual size on the filesystem.

Comment: As far as I can tell, I don't have the compress option set however.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to determine if your file will fit on the media, you have to take into account what the allocation size of the file system is. A file that is 10 bytes long does not occupy 10 bytes on the disk. The space requirement increases in discrete steps, determined by the allocation size (also called cluster size).

See [this Microsoft support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/140365) for more info about NTFS and FAT cluster sizes.

Answer (score 0):

What is `data` in your example above?  How is the binary data represented in the xml file?

It's quite likely that you'll want to do a full serialization into a byte array to get an accurate guess of the size.  The serializer may do arbitrary things like add CDATA tags and if you for some reason need to save the file in UTF-16 instead of UTF-8, well that'll double your size right there probably.

Answer (score 0):

You can save (or write) it to a memory stream then determine how big that memory stream has become, thats the only way to determine the actual size without writing it to disk.

Can't see there being any point to that you may as well just save it a local file, take a look at the final file size then make a choice as to what to do with it.

If all you want to do is make a reasonable estimate of how big a XML file will become once you've added a bunch of encoded binary elements and if we can assume that the rest of the XML will be negligable in comparison to the encoded binary content, then its a matter of determining the bloat introduced due to the encoding.

Typicaly we would encode binary content with base64 encoding which results in 4 bytes of ASCII for every 3 bytes of binary, that is a 33% bloat.  So an estimate would be data.Length * 1.33333